# `flex-col md:flex-row` not working when setting different widths of the child component inside this div

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, nuxt.js, media-queries

I am using Tailwind flex.

I am trying to make auto scroll div when setting different widths of the child component inside this div

BUT: `flex-col md:flex-row` not working?

Please check below details:

div

```
<div class="flex bg-purple-800 overflow-x-auto">
   <component is="my-vue-component" :class="{'w-64':media_mobile,'w-[900px]':media_pc}" />
</div>
```

**control buttons: when click Mobile button, set width 16rem; when click PC button, set width 900px**

```
<button @click="switchmedia(1)">Mobile</button>
<button @click="switchmedia(2)">PC</button>
```

my-vue-component

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-y-4 items-center">
    <div>
      <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold leading-7 text-gray-900 sm:truncate sm:text-3xl sm:tracking-tight">Back End Developer</h2>
      <div class="mt-1 flex flex-wrap md:flex-row gap-x-1 sm:gap-x-2 sm:mt-0">
        <div class="mt-2 flex flex-row items-center text-sm text-gray-500">
          <svg class="mr-1.5 h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 3.75A2.75 2.75 0 018.75 1h2.5A2.75 2.75 0 0114 3.75v.443c.572.055 1.14.122 1.706.2C17.053 4.582 18 5.75 18 7.07v3.469c0 1.126-.694 2.191-1.83 2.54-1.952.599-4.024.921-6.17.921s-4.219-.322-6.17-.921C2.694 12.73 2 11.665 2 10.539V7.07c0-1.321.947-2.489 2.294-2.676A41.047 41.047 0 016 4.193V3.75zm6.5 0v.325a41.622 41.622 0 00-5 0V3.75c0-.69.56-1.25 1.25-1.25h2.5c.69 0 1.25.56 1.25 1.25zM10 10a1 1 0 00-1 1v.01a1 1 0 001 1h.01a1 1 0 001-1V11a1 1 0 00-1-1H10z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            <path d="M3 15.055v-.684c.126.053.255.1.39.142 2.092.642 4.313.987 6.61.987 2.297 0 4.518-.345 6.61-.987.135-.041.264-.089.39-.142v.684c0 1.347-.985 2.53-2.363 2.686a41.454 41.454 0 01-9.274 0C3.985 17.585 3 16.402 3 15.055z" />
          </svg>
          Full-time
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2 flex flex-row items-center text-sm text-gray-500">
          <svg class="mr-1.5 h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.69 18.933l.003.001C9.89 19.02 10 19 10 19s.11.02.308-.066l.002-.001.006-.003.018-.008a5.741 5.741 0 00.281-.14c.186-.096.446-.24.757-.433.62-.384 1.445-.966 2.274-1.765C15.302 14.988 17 12.493 17 9A7 7 0 103 9c0 3.492 1.698 5.988 3.355 7.584a13.731 13.731 0 002.273 1.765 11.842 11.842 0 00.976.544l.062.029.018.008.006.003zM10 11.25a2.25 2.25 0 100-4.5 2.25 2.25 0 000 4.5z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
          Remote
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2 flex flex-row items-center text-sm text-gray-500">
          <svg class="mr-1.5 h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path d="M10.75 10.818v2.614A3.13 3.13 0 0011.888 13c.482-.315.612-.648.612-.875 0-.227-.13-.56-.612-.875a3.13 3.13 0 00-1.138-.432zM8.33 8.62c.053.055.115.11.184.164.208.16.46.284.736.363V6.603a2.45 2.45 0 00-.35.13c-.14.065-.27.143-.386.233-.377.292-.514.627-.514.909 0 .184.058.39.202.592.037.051.08.102.128.152z" />
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-8-6a.75.75 0 01.75.75v.316a3.78 3.78 0 011.653.713c.426.33.744.74.925 1.2a.75.75 0 01-1.395.55 1.35 1.35 0 00-.447-.563 2.187 2.187 0 00-.736-.363V9.3c.698.093 1.383.32 1.959.696.787.514 1.29 1.27 1.29 2.13 0 .86-.504 1.616-1.29 2.13-.576.377-1.261.603-1.96.696v.299a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0v-.3c-.697-.092-1.382-.318-1.958-.695-.482-.315-.857-.717-1.078-1.188a.75.75 0 111.359-.636c.08.173.245.376.54.569.313.205.706.353 1.138.432v-2.748a3.782 3.782 0 01-1.653-.713C6.9 9.433 6.5 8.681 6.5 7.875c0-.805.4-1.558 1.097-2.096a3.78 3.78 0 011.653-.713V4.75A.75.75 0 0110 4z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
          $120k &ndash; $140k
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2 flex flex-row items-center text-sm text-gray-500">
          <svg class="mr-1.5 h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.75 2a.75.75 0 01.75.75V4h7V2.75a.75.75 0 011.5 0V4h.25A2.75 2.75 0 0118 6.75v8.5A2.75 2.75 0 0115.25 18H4.75A2.75 2.75 0 012 15.25v-8.5A2.75 2.75 0 014.75 4H5V2.75A.75.75 0 015.75 2zm-1 5.5c-.69 0-1.25.56-1.25 1.25v6.5c0 .69.56 1.25 1.25 1.25h10.5c.69 0 1.25-.56 1.25-1.25v-6.5c0-.69-.56-1.25-1.25-1.25H4.75z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
          Closing on January 9, 2020
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5 flex lg:ml-4 lg:mt-0">
      <span>
        <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50">
          <svg class="-ml-0.5 mr-1.5 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path d="M2.695 14.763l-1.262 3.154a.5.5 0 00.65.65l3.155-1.262a4 4 0 001.343-.885L17.5 5.5a2.121 2.121 0 00-3-3L3.58 13.42a4 4 0 00-.885 1.343z" />
          </svg>
          Edit
        </button>
      </span>

      <span class="ml-3">
        <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50">
          <svg class="-ml-0.5 mr-1.5 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path d="M12.232 4.232a2.5 2.5 0 013.536 3.536l-1.225 1.224a.75.75 0 001.061 1.06l1.224-1.224a4 4 0 00-5.656-5.656l-3 3a4 4 0 00.225 5.865.75.75 0 00.977-1.138 2.5 2.5 0 01-.142-3.667l3-3z" />
            <path d="M11.603 7.963a.75.75 0 00-.977 1.138 2.5 2.5 0 01.142 3.667l-3 3a2.5 2.5 0 01-3.536-3.536l1.225-1.224a.75.75 0 00-1.061-1.06l-1.224 1.224a4 4 0 105.656 5.656l3-3a4 4 0 00-.225-5.865z" />
          </svg>
          View
        </button>
      </span>

      <span class="ml-3">
        <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600">
          <svg class="-ml-0.5 mr-1.5 h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.704 4.153a.75.75 0 01.143 1.052l-8 10.5a.75.75 0 01-1.127.075l-4.5-4.5a.75.75 0 011.06-1.06l3.894 3.893 7.48-9.817a.75.75 0 011.05-.143z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
          Publish
        </button>
      </span>

      <!-- Dropdown -->

    </div>
  </div>


</template>
```

control script

```
<script setup>

const switchmedia = (t) => {

  if(t === 1) {
    media_mobile.value = true;
    media_pc.value = false;
  }

  if(t === 2) {
    media_mobile.value = false;
    media_pc.value = true;
  }
}

</script>
```

After click PC button, Current Result is:
[image - Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5xmD.png)

What I expected is "flex-row", but as result the two parts are "flex-col".

What I expected:
[image-expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c25fG.png)

I checked the runtime by F12, the css w-900px looks good.
[image - checked css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eK4i.png)

What's the issue? I don't understand why `flex-col md:flex-row` not working.